# Android Material Design: Create theme changer

Tags: java, android, material-design

I was wondering if it's possible to implement a theme changer function in the Material Design, in a case whereby the user can access a settings page and then select say, a night theme (darker components) or a light theme (lighter components). I suppose it will require me to programmatically change the primary colors etc within an onItemClick? I just need to know if this is possible for the material design as I can't seem to find a way to do it online. Would also be grand if someone could tell me briefly the logic to implement such a function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can check my app source code which has this functionality, however I suggest you to create `custom views`  and whenever the user selects a `color` or change the theme you could post an event to the `view` to changes its `color`/`tinting` accordingly.

[Github](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/Fast-Access-Floating-Toolbox-)